# CMAKE- Object library target may not link to anything

Tags: build, cmake

I am getting an error with the cMakeLists.txt file below. The error is

> Object library target "cm" may not link to anything.

The issue is with line `target_link_libraries(cm corebase)`

This builds OK on linux but I this error is occurring on windows.

I'd appreciate any ideas?

```
file(GLOB base
   "*.cpp"
)

file (GLOB model
    "*.cpp"   
)

file(GLOB logger
     "*.cpp"  
)

file(GLOB pass
"*.cpp" 
)

file(GLOB compiler
    "src/compiler/*"
)

add_subdirectory(meta)

if (MSVC)
    add_library(cm OBJECT ${compiler} ${pass})
    add_library(corebase OBJECT ${base} ${logger})
    add_library(model OBJECT ${model})
    target_link_libraries(cm corebase)
    add_dependencies(cm generate-comp-api)
    add_dependencies(model generate-comp-api)
else()
    add_library(cm SHARED ${base} ${logger} ${pass} ${compiler})
    add_library(corebase SHARED ${base} ${logger})
    add_library(model SHARED ${model})
    target_link_libraries(cm corebase metamodel)
    add_dependencies(cm generate-comp-api)
    add_dependencies(model generate-comp-api)
    add_subdirectory(python/api)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
    add_subdirectory(contrib/googletest)
    #add_subdirectory(recordings)
endif(MSVC)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is correct: [OBJECT libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) shouldn't link to anything. Instead, one need to use *object files*, corresponded to the library, as  **source files** for executable/other library:

```
# Create an OBJECT library
add_library(corebase OBJECT ${base} ${logger})
# And use its objects for other library.
add_library(cm OBJECT ${compiler} ${pass} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:corebase>)
```

Comment: Actually starting from CMake 3.12 it **is** possible to link libraries also to OBJECT targets.